# Visualizing H5 Model Using TensorBoard

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorboard

I already created model that took several hours using google colaboratory, when creating it also I implement to create tensorboard callback.But, when I done with the project, I save the model, but forget to save the tensorboard log.

Is there anyway to visualize the saved model (model.h5) using tensorboard without running the training process again?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: You need to save tensorboard logs through callback to visualize them . But you can view your model architecture through netron webapp.  
         https://netron.app/                          
         https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs